# Dynamically add fields to CollectionType

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-forms

I have to create a school manager. When a teacher has to submit the results of an evaluation, he has to assess given skills by a scoring grade.

`Evaluation` ------OneToMany------ `Scale` ------ManyToOne------ `Skill`

**EvaluationType**

```
class EvaluationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('scales', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ScaleType::class
            ]);
    }
}
```

**ScaleType**

```
class ScaleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('value');
    }
}
```

I want to dynamically add `ScaleType` children to `EvaluationType::scales` form child for a given collection of `Skill`s.

Here is what I've tried so far in my controller action :

```
public function newEvaluation(Classroom $classroom, Subject $subject, Period $period)
{
    $evaluation = new Evaluation();
    $evaluation->setClassroom($classroom);
    $evaluation->setSubject($subject);
    $evaluation->setPeriod($period);

    $form = $this->createForm(EvaluationType::class, $evaluation);
    $skills =$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Skill')->findAll();
    foreach($skills as $skill) {
        $scale = new Scale();
        $scale->setEvaluation($evaluation);
        $scale->setSkill($skill);
        $form['scales']->add($this->createForm(ScaleType::class, $scale, [
            'auto_initialize' => false
        ]));
    }

    return $this->render('classrooms/newEvaluation.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'classroom' => $classroom,
        'subject' => $subject
    ]);
}
```

The problem is that I only get a single sub-form in the `scales` field on rendering, looks like when I add a children to `$form['scales']` it overwrites the previous children.

I suppose I'm doing it totally wrong. How can I achieve that ?

I'm also pointing out the fact that I can't create the `Evaluation` first and then, on another page, create all the `Scale`s. It needs to be done in the same controller/page.

**Edit**: I'll add the fact that I don't want the children of `scales` to be extensible, they have to be fixed by the server, and not being fetched by the client.

Comment: Try using your `foreach` to create a collection of `Scale` and add it to your `Evaluation` by using `addScales()` for example, with no form interaction at all. Then when you've populated your entity create your `EvaluationType` form.

Comment: Works great ! What really did it is creating the form after hydrating the model. Does `$this->createForm` makes a copy of the data passed in 2nd parameter ?

Comment: There are various kinds of `DataTransformers` in Symfony which handles this kind of work, so you can get a well formatted form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, thanks to Artamiel, here is my new controller action :

```
public function newEvaluation(Classroom $classroom, Subject $subject, Period $period)
{
    $evaluation = new Evaluation();
    $evaluation->setClassroom($classroom);
    $evaluation->setSubject($subject);
    $evaluation->setPeriod($period);

    $skills = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Skill')->findAll();
    foreach ($skills as $skill) {
        $scale = new Scale();
        $scale->setSkill($skill);
        $scale->setEvaluation($evaluation);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(EvaluationType::class, $evaluation);

    return $this->render('classrooms/newEvaluation.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'classroom' => $classroom,
        'subject' => $subject
    ]);
}
```